# Canvas sizing incorrectly on loading

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas webpage that functionally works but occasionally sizes incorrectly on start up.
Says I have declared a canvas html tag like this:

```
<canvas id="main_canvas"></canvas>
```

And I have included a javascript file that takes care of the sizing using jquery

```
$(function() {
    var canvas = $('canvas')[0];

    var DISPLAY_WIDTH = window.innerWidth-10,
        DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 620,
```

Occasionally after the  page loads the canvas size is squeezed into a very small area and all objects rendered is stacked upon each other, if I refresh however this problem no longer persists. I use the inspect element tool and found that while the sizing problem happens I have the html code

```
<canvas id="main_canvas" width="-10" height="620"></canvas>
```

Seems for some unknown reason the `window.innerwidth` is not acquired and the width is simply set to -10 and causes the problem. But the jquery declaration `$(function(){})` should only execute after the page loads and I don't think I can use `window.innerWidth` just in the html tag. And I don't want to set the width to some other numerical value since this problem might as well happen again and I simply get that numerical width as my canvas width.

Anyway can tell me some fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if you put it all in the

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

function? Quote:

> Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before
>   the page contents are loaded.
>   (Source: http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)