# window.innerWidth = 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm making a canvas webpage for animation. Strange thing is that every time I launch the webpage from double clicking the html file the canvas will almost always size incorrectly. I have post a similar question before: [Canvas sizing incorrectly on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643826/canvas-sizing-incorrectly-on-loading/11643889#11643889) but have no desired answer.

After extensive debugging I find out that it's the `window.innerWidth` that's giving me such trouble. The `window.innerWidth` returns 0 every time the page is launched from double clicking the html file and results in a incorrect canvas size (interestingly the canvas size is not exactly 0, but a very small one that has object to be rendered stack on top of one another), but after reloading the page (Ctrl+R) the problem no longer happens. I'm using jQuery to load the page, here is my code:

html:

```
    <body>
        <canvas id="main_canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
```

js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth-10,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-10;

        if (window.innerWidth === 0) { alert("wtf? width = 0?");}

        var canvas = $('canvas')[0],
            context;

        init(); // use $(window).load(init) does not fix the problem

        function init() {

            if (canvas.getContext) {

                context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        animate(); // draw stuff
            }

            else {
                alert('Your browser does not support html5 canvas');
            }
        }
});
```

As you can see here, I'm already using `$(docuemnt).ready(function())` to make sure things gets loaded, however from a link http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ the author suggest that the document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet.

On the other hand the `$(window).load(function())` executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images. Therefore functions which concern images or other page contents should be placed in the load event for the window or the content tag itself. But even I use this the problem is not solved.

Maybe the js file is asking for window's width before it's loaded, but I can't find a viable solution. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The `innerWidth` is a window/frame property and is available even before anything was loaded – yet even in an empty document. Which browser are you using to see this problem? I would guess it is a bug. `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type="text/javascript"> alert( window.innerWidth ); </script></head></html>` prints 1920, which is my screens width…

Comment: @feeela I'm using chrome and have this problem. The script tag you give prints 0 for me, but guess what? After it prints 0 and problem disappears and the `alert("wtf? width = 0?");` doesn't show up even it's previously printed 0, but if I remove this script tag the same thing happens

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `window.outerWidth` which is returning 0 on some browsers when called from the ready() method, and I solved it by using `screen.width` instead. 
I didn't test it but I think that `screen.availWidth` would solve your issue.

Comment: Still sounds like a browser bug…

Comment: @feeela where should I report it?

Comment: window.outerWidth and screen.width measure two different things - the width of your browser window and the width of your whole screen. Likewise window.innerWidth and screen.availWidth are not the same.

Answer (score 7):

Use an event listener that triggers on a window resize. That way you don't have to do any nonsense with trying to find when the window fully initializes. It will also make you less dependent on state which is a nice bonus.

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false ); 
function onWindowResize() {
    windowX = window.innerWidth;
    windowY = window.innerHeight;
}
```